# Tensorboard : Error metadata.tsv is not a file

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am manually trying to link `embedding` tensor with `metadata.tsv`, but I am getting following error: `"$LOG_DIR/metadata.tsv is not a file."`

I am running Tensorboard with following command : 
`tensorboard --logdir default/` 
and my `projector_config.pbtxt` file is following :

```
embeddings {
  tensor_name: 'embedding/decoder_embedding_matrix'
  metadata_path: '$LOG_DIR/metadata.tsv'
  }
```

I have checked my log_dir and it has all files. [Screen shot attached]

**LOG_DIR Screenshot**:

[image]

**Error Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Did the solution work??

Answer (score 2):

It cannot recognize `$LOG_DIR` the way you have used it. Either edit `projector_config.pbtxt` manually to provide the full path, or use this in your code:

```
import os
embedding.metadata_path = os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'metadata.tsv')
```

where again `LOG_DIR` should preferably be the full path (and not the relative one).